# Developing a graphical user interface in Python / connecting GUI to other code?

Tags: python, user-interface, software-design

I just want to know if this is possible or if I need to look for other options...

I am trying to develop medical software for heart disease diagnosis, and already coded the machine learning algorithm to analyze patient data. It is a .py file, and the algorithm outputs a heart disease severity score from 0-4.

I would like to incorporate this algorithm into a desktop application that gives the user (a doctor) an input field for the given patient's information, and then allows the doctor to run the algorithm I have coded (ideally by clicking a button, or other intuitive process) and then view the results for this one patient.

Is this possible to do in Python / PyQT for developing the interface and connecting it to the algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. PyQt might be the most stable way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and fairly straightforward too. [Here is a decent PyQt5 tutorial series](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) to start with.

Comment: Thank you! What would be the procedure to link a button to running the code file?